# Creating strong names in .NET using Strong Name Tool

Tags: .net, visual-studio, strongname

After getting the instruction from google, I've tried to create StrongNameFile with the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\sn -k StrongNameFile.snk
```

When I ran the command, I got an error message:

```
'sn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I tried it in the following way:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SDK\v3.5\Bin>sn -k StrongNameFile.snk
```

But got the same error. Please somebody help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 10):

Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt instead of a normal command prompt.  (Start > Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 > Visual Studio Tools > Visual Studio Command Prompt.)  This will set up your PATH to include the .NET Framework SDK directories, which include `sn.exe`.

If you need to set up the path manually for your own scripts or command prompts, the path you need is:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin`

(Exact version number may vary.)

Comment: Hi itowlson,
I am using Visual Studio Express Edition 2008, there i cant find the command prompt from tools menu....Pls tell me in Express Edition 2008 where can i find this command prompt???

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I don't have access to Express Edition.  But if you are using VS, you don't need to run sn -k: just go to Project > Properties > Signing tab, check the "Sign the assembly" check box, and select "New..." in the drop-down box.  Or if you really need the command-line utility, and if Express doesn't give you the `Microsoft SDKs` path I mentioned, you can download the Windows SDK from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/windows/bb980924%28en-us%29.aspx?wt.svl=more_downloads (you only need the .NET Framework bits).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a DOS command prompt. You actually want a Visual Studio Command Prompt when executing sn.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt shortcut in your Start menu:

All Programs | Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 | Visual Studio Tools | Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt.

In that, use command "sn".

That shortcut sets up the path environment vars you need.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to all the other answers here, you could have searched your hard disk for sn.exe...

Answer (score 0):

this works in below steps:
If you have Visual Studio 2012/2013, open the command prompt of visual studio then browse to the path 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\SDK\v3.5\Bin>
then run below commands
Create the key file by running this command: sn -k c:\pairkey.snk
Extract the public key to file: sn -p c:\pairkey.snk c:\pubkey
Extract public key and public key token from file: sn -tp c:\pubkey

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Developer Command Prompt for visual studio by searching on start menu.

Step 2:C:\Windows\system32> it will come on command promt.

Step 3:chnage the directory on your wish .You can give your solution directory like .cd D:\Learning\Projects\Biztalk\EAISchemas

Step 4: In command prompt, from the folder where you want to store the key file, type the following command, and ENTER:

sn /k file_name .snk

Example: sn /k ErrorHandlingProcess.snk

The above Step can be followed for any Visual Studio Solution